# capture all proxytunnel output to a file

Tags: output, io-redirection, proxytunnel

When I use an ssh command with proxytunnel I always get an output like

```
 Via xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa:pppp -> bbb.ccc.ddd.eee:443 -> remotesvr:22
```

before I get the output of my command

I want to capture all output to a file including the `"Via ..."` stuff.

As an example using the `*ls*` command I tried

```
*ssh remotesvr ls 2>&1 > $TMPfile*
```

but the `Via xxx...` line still gets to my terminal instead of `$TMPfile`.

How can I get all output captured to `$TMPfile?`